# Set NumberPicker value with Robotium

Tags: android, robotium, numberpicker

What is the best way to currently **set** a **NumberPicker value** using **Robotium**?

With Robotium 5.3.1, there is no way to directly set its value as in previous releases (using *setNumberPicker* method) so, is there any workaround for this?

EDIT: In my case, I have 2 NumberPicker's and 1 DatePicker inside a dialog. As soon as I set a DatePicker value, the dialog gets dismissed, so I cannot set the NumberPicker values.

[image]

The xml layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/reminder_hour_numberpicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/task_details_item_duration_space"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/task_details_item_duration_space"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="@dimen/header"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/reminder_minute_numberpicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/reminder_datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    </DatePicker>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Robotium step in my code is:

```
final DatePicker dpDate = (DatePicker) solo.getView(R.id.reminder_datePicker);
final DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now().plusDays(WHEN_TO_INTEGER.get(when));
solo.setDatePicker(dpDate, dateTime.getYear(), dateTime.getMonthOfYear() - 1, dateTime.getDayOfMonth());

solo.waitForView(R.id.reminder_hour_numberpicker);
solo.waitForView(R.id.reminder_minute_numberpicker);
final NumberPicker npHour = (NumberPicker) solo.getView(R.id.reminder_hour_numberpicker);
final NumberPicker npMinutes = (NumberPicker) solo.getView(R.id.reminder_minute_numberpicker);
final int displayedValueIndex = minutes / 15;
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        npHour.setValue(hour);
        npMinutes.setValue(displayedValueIndex);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is can be a solution to your problem :

1. Find NumberPicker using getView

   `NumberPicker myNumberPicker = (NumberPicker) Solo.getView(R.id.xxxx);`
2. Use the following method to set its value

`public void setNumberPicker(final NumberPicker numberPicker, final int value) {
        if (numberPicker != null && getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    numberPicker.setValue(value);
                }
            });
        }
    }`